# Order By Select Data as per the comma separated ID values '3,4,5' stored in column SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

How can i return the order of data as per comma separated is stored in other table after that other data (preferred IDs on top)

[Please find more explanation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNopf.jpg)

Comment: You would start by providing some details about what you are asking. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: And for what it is worth, storing delimited data like that is a horribly bad way to deal with data.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I updated one of the image for more better explaination

Comment: Instead of a picture could you read the article I linked and provide details so others can use it? And those delimited values are a nightmare to work with like that.

Comment: And from your extremely vague description this is already happening. The only values in your picture are also in your delimited string. I think it might be time you step back a little bit and try to explain this more clearly.

Comment: Since you are starting, the best way is to re-design your database structure.  This is a disaster waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

To do this sort of ordering, you need to create a virtual column that has your ordering in it, then order your data by that column. Something like this example

```
Select * from 
    (Select *, case ResourceCategory when 44 then 1. when 42 then 2, when 72 then 3 else 4 end as PriorityOrder from dataTable) A
Order by PriorityOrder
```

In order to create this ordering in code from a string, you would have to create your query as dynamic sql, and build the case statement from that string.

Comment: I receive ID's Dynamically , this would work if they are static

Comment: As I said, you need to create your own version of the case statement each time from the string you receive. Split the string into IDs, create the query and the case statement from them as a string, then EXEC the resulting string to actually run the query. Read up on Dynamic SQL.